# How to Interactive Sort by Calculated Columns in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a calculate field Total Pts which is the sum of the values of report items

=ReportItems!Textbox28.Value + ReportItems!Textbox30.Value + ReportItems!Textbox32.Value

Now I want to put a interactive sort here and I am not able to do so . Any ideas? I can't do it in  a query because the reportitems that I am adding are from a two different datasets which are of diff. types eg: sql server & sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue with doing this because SSRS allows you to use an expression to determine the sort order. Just right click on your header textbox for the column and go to the interactive sort tab. Here you can turn interactive sort on, then in the sort by field click the function icon next to the drop down. Use the same expression that you used for your calculated field, and it will sort according to the results of this expression. If there is some reason you can't do this that I'm missing, let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: ya I know that, but what I am using are ReportItems and it gives me an error : Report items cannot be used in the sort expression.

Comment: Do those textboxes referenced have expressions themselves? Are they in separate tablix? Depending on the setup here, it may make sense to just explicitly define the values by writing out the expressions for each of these textboxes. I realize it may get lengthy due to the lookups involved.